# Saving user inputs to an existing text file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

How would I go about saving a user form input from a view to an existing text file with the ASP.NET MVC framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to start of, you would accept some code from the user and then save it:

```
string userInput =Console.Readline();
```

Then you would use the code `WriteAllText()`. This allows you to create a new file and writes the contents to it. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.
So basically:

```
string userInput =Console.Readline();
File.WriteAllText("thenameyouwanttogivetoyourfile.txt", userInput);
```

This reads the file and then outputs it

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText("thenameyouwanttogivetoyourfile.txt");  
Console.WriteLine(readText);
```

Thats how you create a new file. To overwrite a file that already exists, you do the same thing but with the keyword `Create()`. This creates or overwrites a file and if you want to replace the contents of one file with another, use `Replace()`.

For futher help try this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it works for you. This way, it saves other people time and effort.

Comment: I need a bit more guidance about how this would work in the MVC framework